# How to generate CSS file using javascript in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that will allow the user to choose the background color or font on the page and based on his choice a CSS file will be generated. Then the file would be injected into the page.

I've already tried to write some separate functions, every function for different elements and it's working great but 1) changes are not saved on the page, 2) functions are redundant, 3) I have no idea how to generate a CSS file from this.

This are chunks of code from content script I've already written (every function looks kinda similar):

```
colorPicker.onchange = function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0].id,
        {code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "' + colorPicker.value + '";'}
    )
})}
```

I also know that to inject CSS to page from chrome extension I can use:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {
 file : "mystyle.css"
});
```

I really want to generate a CSS file instead of changing document properties one by one; but... how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In short, Chrome extensions can't write to arbitrary local files without resorting to some workaround like nativeMessaging to run a separate utility that does the dirty work or use the bleeding edge Native File System API available since Chrome 86. You can use chrome.tabs.insertCSS with a literal `code` to insert the generated code. To apply it automatically use chrome.storage and chrome.tabs.onUpdated or chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought about, however the main goal of this extension is to generate some sort of CSS that I can download in a .css file form, the insertCSS is a minor property

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to make something like Stylebot (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) but a lot simpler, with some other options, without monaco editor and only for personal use

Comment: Downloading would be a trivial addition, see examples of downloading generated text from JS.